# RAD Studio 10.2 (C++): ~TControl() destructor only works on every second iteration

Tags: runtime-error, c++builder, destructor

Whenever I try to run the `~TControl();` destructor on some child TPanel controls (components) that were created at runtime, it only destructs every **second** child Panel (e.g. see the code below).

```
for(int i=0; i < ParentPanel->ControlCount; i++)
{
    ParentPanel->Controls[i]->~TControl();
}
```

It only destructs the remaining child TPanel controls if I run the 'for' loop again and again (I have no idea why).

Now if I try to program it to 'manually' destruct all the child controls that I know I'm going to create at runtime (let's say 4 child TPanel controls), it gives me a `"List index out of bounds(#)"` error, where `#` is half the total number of the controls that I construct and tell it to manually destruct.

```
ParentPanel->Controls[0]->~TControl();
ParentPanel->Controls[1]->~TControl();
ParentPanel->Controls[2]->~TControl();
ParentPanel->Controls[3]->~TControl();
```

e.g. The above would cause it to display a `"List index out of bounds (2)"` error.

The same thing happens even if I use the `delete ParentPanel->Controls[0];` method instead.

Any clues? Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that calling destructor directly is good idea. And when you remove the element from array, the size of array will decrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing items from an indexed list should ideally be done backwards:

```
for (int i = ParentPanel->ControlCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    delete ParentPanel->Controls[i];
}
```

#### The problem with counting up

Such lists usually shift all items "above" (with a higher index) down, so if Controls[i] was deleted, now a new control is moved to that index. But directly after, the index is incremented, so that it points to the item above the one that replaced the deleted one, and only that is removed. So, in effect, only every second item is removed.

```
Initially:      [A]  B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J    i = 0
```

*The index is indicated by* `[ ]`

Now you delete and thus remove A, so the new order is:

```
                [B]  C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J        i = 0
```

But the loop immediately increments the index:

```
                 B  [C]  D   E   F   G   H   I   J        i++, so i = 1
```

so in the next loop, C gets deleted (which means that B is skipped). And so on, and so forth. This means that only every second element gets removed.

*But if you start at the top, no elements are being moved, so everything gets deleted.*

#### Calling the destructor

It seems to me an extremely bad idea to call the destructor directly. Rather use `delete`.

#### Components

Note that if you want to remove all components, you should use the `Components` list and `ComponentCount` instead.

Comment: Yes, true. Just a note that in this case, the Panel's child components are owned by the Form, rather than the Panel, so I could not use `ParentPanel->Components[i];` or `ParentPanel->ComponentCount;`.

Also, could someone please upvote either my post above or my answer below, so that I have enough reputation for my votes to change the publicly displayed post score? Thank you. (I'm trying to upvote this answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @Axbor Axrorov said, it turned out to be the size of the array decreasing as each child control was destructed / deleted.

I found out that one way to do it was to use the decrement operator `--` when deleting the child controls, so that as the integer in the 'for' loop increases, it keeps deleting the first element in the array as it continues to decrease in size (see code below).

```
for(int i=0; i<ParentPanel->ControlCount; i++)
{
    if(ParentPanel->Controls[i] != NULL)
    {
        delete ParentPanel->Controls[i--];
    }
}
```

Comment: In effect, i will remain 0: i-- and i++ cancel each other out. Also, before the i++, your i will be negative. Fortunately, you do a post-increment, otherwise things would go crazy.

Comment: A much better solution would be to simply add the desired child controls to your own list/array first and then loop through that instead however you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete controls instead of calling destructor.

```
while(ParentPanel->ControlCount > 0)
    delete ParentPanel->Controls[0];
```